# Effects of a constant on a function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Consider $f(x,t) = \frac{1}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{-2\sin (\pi n/4)+2 \sin(3\pi n/4)}{\pi n}\cdot e^{-((\pi n)^2 + c)t} \cos(\pi n x)$ where c is a constant. I am trying to determine the effects of $c$ on $f(x,t)$ as $t$ increases. That is what happens when $c > 0$ and $c < 0$. For simplicity, let $c \in \mathbb{Z}. $ For $c > 0$, I am confident that the function converges to $1/2$. However, when $c < 0$, I see $f(x,t)$ diverges for large values of $t$ only when $c \leq -40$. For other values of $c$ ($0 > c > -40$), the function still converges to $1/2$. I noticed $\pi^22^2 \approx 39.5$. I have used Matlab for my plots and I set the upper bound on $n = 20$. I am not sure what is special about $c = -40$.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: What happens when $c < 0$? and why?

Comment: The numerator $-2\sin (\pi n/4)+2 \sin(3\pi n/4)$ is nonzero only for $n = 2,6,10,14,...$.  The exponential factor goes to zero for large $t$ as long as $(\pi n)^2 + c$ is positive.  However, when $c \lt -4\pi^2$, the second term of the series diverges for large $t$.